# IE 8 Chinese encoding characters

Tags: encoding, utf-8, cjk, ie8-compatibility-mode

I am unable to render Chinese characters in IE 8. I have researched this and I am aware of the meta tag to force compatibility mode.  I am also aware of the language pack you can install. 
Finally I have seen that Microsoft actually forces IE7 compatibility mode on their Chinese website. http://www.microsoft.com/zh/cn/default.aspx

I am wondering if anyone has any alternatives solutions to this problem. None them seem that appealing to me. I am using utf8 as my encoding and this problem only occurs in IE8.

Comment: Could you post a short-but-complete sample of html in which this error occurs? How are you generating your web pages?

Comment: Pages are generated via php and characters show up correctly in IE7, FF3, Chrome on multiple OS platforms. The headers sent by the server do show it as UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something that appears to work. After reading this question ( [How can I make Chinese characters show in IE8 without forcing compatibility mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867678/how-can-i-make-chinese-characters-show-in-ie8-without-forcing-compatibility-mode) ) I ended up using the style below. The style uses a backup font of Arial, Arial Unicode MS.

To call this you SHOULD use IE conditionals for only IE8. Be aware this may have some issues in browsers other than IE8. See http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=3c8cf2891a0bcfe5&hl=en

Also please note Arial MS unicode is installed on Vista and XP and is also bundled with OS X 10.5 and later. It does not ship with Windows 7 but is distributed with Microsoft Office. For more info see: http://emailmarketingvoodoo.com/blog/post/arial-unicode-ms-your-safest-bet-for-consistent-foreign-language-display/

So here is the code:

```
body {
    font-family:Arial,Arial Unicode MS;
}
```

With this you can avoid the need to call the ugly meta tag to force IE8 into compatibility mode.