# HTML web page doctype declaration issue

Tags: html, utf-8

i am designing a webpage which should support the all languages `utf-8`. unfortunately some language characters are not recognising on IE but it loks fine on mozilla & chrome, why ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head> <body>
  <p>Chinese Text : &#24744;&#22909;&#19990;&#30028; </p>
  <p> Indian text : &#2361;&#2375;&#2354;&#2379; &#2357;&#2367;&#2358;&#2381;&#2357; </p>
</body>
</html>
```

but when i remove the very first line, characters shows on `internet explorer (IE)` too.

```
Removed : <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Can someone explain please, what should be correct doctype declaration for multilingual support.

Comment: Characters show up fine here (IE8 on Vista). But, why are you setting `charset` to `ISO-8859-1` if you want `UTF-8`?

Comment: opps :( typo mistake. sorry, let me edit

Comment: The charset shouldn't matter if you specify the chinese text as character references. In theory, any charset will do. So the real question is, why does IE8 show the characters in quirks mode but not in standards mode. The problem does occur here in IE8 under XP.

Comment: What happens when IE 8 does not show the characters? Are they completely missing, or do some boxes or some wrong characters appear instead? (I suspect a font problem, or rather that IE 8 is incapable of using fallback fonts.)

Comment: @MrLister: yes you are right.  problem does occur in IE8 under XP

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela : some boxes appears instead of chinese characters.

Answer (score 12):

Your `charset` is currently set to `ISO-8859-1`, which is the character set for Western European characters. Change it to `UTF-8` to have support for all the Unicode characters:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: But this is not the answer, as IE8 has the same problem after you specify UTF-8.

Comment: @user1010399: What shows up in place of the characters you are trying to type?

Comment: some boxes appears instead of characters

Answer (score 0):

Check out answers to question [3867678](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867678/how-can-i-make-chinese-characters-show-in-ie8-without-forcing-compatibility-mode). They seem to say that IE 8 has by default no font set for Chinese characters (though I suppose this applies to some installations only). Setting the font in CSS should help, though I’m not sure what might be an optimal font family list; maybe something like

```
font-family: Arial Unicode MS, PMingLiU, MingLiU, SimSun
```